# SG-U body switching and ethics

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

Okay, so I'm re-watching season 1 of Stargate Universe. And there's some body switching (mind taking over someone else). Now, in a few of these episodes, there's some people having sex, making out, drinking, etc. During these times, was there nothing in place to prevent people from doing this? What if the someone got pregnant? What if someone was a recovering alcoholic, and went back to his body drunk? Were these never discussed? How ethical is it for Destiny members to do this to the people they take over?

Comment: https://archive.today/20130619180408/www.afterellen.com/blog/sarahwarn/stargate-universe-responds-to-controversy

Comment: I believe everyone is aware of the trade-offs of body swapping. They accept the risks, just as those waiting on Earth accept the risks. "How ethical is it" isn't really a question that can be objectively answered here.

Answer (score 12):

There is some kind of contract or protocol which the stone users have to sign and abide by. We don't know the exact terms, but at the least it seems designed to allow the use of bodies for personal (and sexual) uses, and it acknowledges the risk of death for both parties.

The best source of info for this topic is the Kino webisode *We Volunteer To Do This*.

> Eli Wallace: Doesn’t make you wonder, though, like what Chole’s doing now? I mean, back on Earth? Don’t get me wrong, I mean, I would…she would never do anything, you know, *weird*, to…while she’s in…you know…
>
> Airman Kelly (in Chloe’s body): Yeah, yeah, we, we um…we sign permission forms.
>
> Eli: Oh. Um, what do they say?
>
> Kelly: Uh, something like: “I hereby give consent for the temporary use of my body,” blah, blah, blah…for, ya know, personal stuff.
>
> Eli: Stuff? Like what, does it say?
>
> Kelly: No, but folks are visiting their husbands and wives or boyfriends and girlfriends. I mean, that’s kind of the point, right? *(laughs)*
>
> Eli: *(Incredulous)* And that doesn’t *bother* you?
>
> Kelly: Hey, man! Privacy sort of goes out the window both ways. I had a shower this morning in this body. […]
>
> Eli: The form though, what does the form say?
>
> Kelly: *(Thinking)* Um…uh…Oh yeah: “I acknowledge that the death of a person on either side of the connection may result in the death of the other.”
>
> Eli: Yeah, nobody really knows if that’s the way it would…uh, anyway, um… Is there anything you can or can’t do, like, while you’re here?
>
> Kelly: Uh, I’m supposed to be careful…and not do anything that might impact negatively on relationships between personnel on the ship.
>
> Eli: Ah, “the fragile balance”… *(laughs)*
>
> Kelly: Too bad, you are kind of cute.

Comment: An excellent find. I doubt that you'll see better than this.

Comment: We don't see the other end of the stone, but wonder how old the person is who came across. She called Eli "kid", like he was much younger than her (Eli is young, but not that young). It also leaves to the imagination what she was wanting to do while in Chloe's body ... haha. Agree with @Richard. This is an excellent find.